# Not authorized to upload a file using Microsoft graph api

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Im trying to upload a new file to my MS teams onedrive, through my custom teams app. However, even though my app is registered and my user has the right permissions, its still not allowing me to do the PUT, whats going wrong here?

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      microsoftTeams.getContext(resolve);
    })
    fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/sites/OpenSesameTest/Shared%20Documents/General/FileB.txt:/', {        
      method: 'PUT',
      body: "Hello World",
      headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT', 'Authorization': 'Bearer'}
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Success:', result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  }
  
  render() {  
      return (     
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>Select file to upload</label>
            <input type="file"></input>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>     
      );
    }
  }

export default Tab;
```

[image: 401 Unauthorized]

Comment: Are you passing the access token in authorization header? Please check the token in [jwt.io](https://www.jwt.io) or any other token decoder and verify if the required permissions are available.

Comment: Can you please share the details about the Graph API you are using? It seems like graph API used in code snipper is not correct.

Comment: What do you mean? Im trying to access my MS teams onedrive through: https://graph.microsoft.com/sites/OpenSesameTest/Shared%20Documents/General/FileB.txt:/

The documentation is extremely confusing as it just says: PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
But this is obviously not a approachable URL. 

What URL should i be using in order to upload to my teams onedrive?

Comment: Could you share the response body with the request id and timestamp.

Comment: This is a [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68629060/not-authorized-to-upload-a-file-using-microsoft-graph-api) question

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT youre linking to this question...